# Python Turtle Scrollbars

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Does anyone know how to prevent scrollbars appearing on the Turtle Graphics window in Python for small window sizes please?

The following code produces the image below. For a screen of 600px by 600px the scrollbars do not appear.

```
import turtle

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
TRIANGLE_SIZE = 120

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)

triangle = turtle.Turtle("triangle")
triangle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / TURTLE_SIZE)
triangle.color("pink")
triangle.right(30)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to prevent scrollbars appearing on the Turtle
>   Graphics window in Python

The answer is probably to use turtle *embedded* in tkinter rather than *standalone*.  As standalone turtle uses `ScrolledCanvas` by default, whereas embedded turtle allows you to use it, or simply stick with the basic `Canvas`.

That said, here are three different ways to achieve this using standalone turtle:

1) Simply increase your square window from 400 x 400 to 420 x 420:

```
screen.setup(420, 420)
```

This works because turtle has stored in it's global `_CFG` configuration dictionary default sizes for the window and canvas:

```
_CFG = {
    "width" : 0.5,  # Screen
    "height" : 0.75,
    "canvwidth" : 400,
    "canvheight": 300,
    # ...
    }
```

Below this canvas size, scrollbars appear.  Except there's a fudge factor to account for window *chrome* which we can see in `setworldcoordinates()`:

```
 self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
```

So any window 420 x 320, or larger, shouldn't get scrollbars by default unless the canvas is also readjusted.

2) Manipulate the `_CFG` dictionary via the `"turtle.cfg"` file.  Unlike the faux `_pd` pen dictionary that's created on the fly by the `turtle.pen()` method, there is no runtime user interface for the `turtle._CFG` dictionary unless we poke around under the hood:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, _CFG

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
TRIANGLE_SIZE = 120

_CFG.update({"canvwidth": 380, "canvheight": 380})  # 400 - 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)

triangle = Turtle("triangle")
triangle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / TURTLE_SIZE)
triangle.color("pink")
triangle.right(30)

screen.exitonclick()
```

3) Patch the `setupcanvas` method of standalone turtle's `_Root` class to substitute generic `Canvas` for `ScrolledCanvas`.  This eliminates the need for any magic numbers and will simply turn off scrolling:

```
import tkinter as TK
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, _Root

def setupcanvas(self, width, height, cwidth, cheight):
    self._canvas = TK.Canvas(self, width=cwidth, height=cheight)
    self._canvas.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

_Root.setupcanvas = setupcanvas

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
TRIANGLE_SIZE = 120

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)

# ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

Ensuring that the margin value is the smallest as possible will make that the origin of the canva's cartesian plane is as closer as possible to the center of the screen. I have a utility class that I put on the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607072/how-to-calculate-canvas-size-to-avoid-scrollbars-on-turtles-screen) that helps adjusting window's properties to figure out the best value for `margin`

I came across this question while learning about [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html). The following approach worked for me:

```
from turtle import Turtle

donatello = Turtle("turtle")
donatello.color("purple")  # just to keep it real
screen = donatello.getscreen()
window_width = 200
window_height = 250
margin = 2  # minimum difference between window size and canvas size to avoid scrollbars
screen.screensize(  # despite the name, screensize() does not change window/screen's size
    canvwidth=window_width - margin,  # named parameters give a hint of method's real goal
    canvheight=window_height - margin)  # canvas has to be smaller than window
screen.setup(window_width, window_height)  # setup() will change window/screen's size
print(f"screensize(canvas) = {screen.screensize()}\n"
      f"screen(width*height) = ({screen.window_width()} * {screen.window_height()})")
screen.exitonclick()
```

output:

```
screensize(canvas) = (198, 248)
screen(width*height) = (200 * 250)
```

Basically is just ensuring that the canvas is a few units smaller than the screen dimensions, and just beware of the deceiving [`screensize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.screensize) method.

[image: turtle screen without scrollbars]